# TypeError: $http is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Script:

```
app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("controlador", ["$scope", function($scope, $http){
$scope.items = [];

$scope.submitForm = function() {
        // Posting data to php file
        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'http://localhost/nfe/admin/nfephp-master/exemplos/NFe/4.00testaMakeNFe.php',
          data    : $scope.items, //forms user object
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
}]);
```

Formulário:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()">
 ...
</form>
```

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode estar causando esse erro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta faltando você declarar a importação dele:

```
app.controller("controlador", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
```